# How to Loop through an array in Angular template to show different colored tile showing regular pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-routing, angular-promise

[tile view images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPqde.png)

These are the color of tiles i want to show when i loop from 0 to 11 as number of records in array is 12 each for every tile.

Red color for : 0,4,8,12 index

Green for : 1,5,9 index

Yellow for: 2, 6, 10 index

Blue color for: 3, 7, 11 index

Comment: Please, you may refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you since your question is really messy. In general, that's what you might be looking for (it's typescript):

```
yourArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index == 0 || index == 4 || index == 8 || index == 12) {
    item.color = "red";
  }
  else if (index == 1 || index == 5 || index == 9) {
    item.color = "green";
  }
  else if (index == 2 || index == 6 || index == 10) {
    item.color = "yellow";
  }
  else {
    item.color = "blue";
  }
}
)
```

Comment: Well, if you use different color for each 4 items then you will have to write all the conditions. If pattern is the same for all 200 items you can use modulo operation. Something like this:
if (index%12 == 2 || index%12 == 6 || index%12 == 10) {
    item.color = "yellow";
  }

Comment: thanxx stefaniak.people who try to understand who puts effort to understand are better than who rather say chuck it!